# setting html <select> option to be the default value based on current time

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have made a basic punchclock webpage & MySQL database,
only problem is when people accidently clock in instead of out at end of day or vice versa it leaves alot of gaps.

I need some sort of code that defaults "startfinish" value to "Start" before 10:30 and "End" after 14:30 but still allows the user to change the option if they needed to

note really sure where to start and if i should use javascript or php (php is in a seperate file as the "form action")

heres my current html code that needs the option changed:

```
<select name="startfinish" id="startend" required>
                <option selected="selected" disabled selection>Please select</option>
                <option value="Start">Start</option>
                <option value="End">End</option>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks,

Danial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't opposed to PHP you could check the current time and compare it against the times you've specified. This will have to go in the file you're working from though, not your action file.

```
<?php

// Set the default timezone so you don't run into timezone issues
// You can set this to whatever suits your application best
// Full list of supported timezones here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver');

// Compare the current time to the start and end times
// This reads: if current time is before start time, option is selected, otherwise it's not
$start = (strtotime('now') < strtotime('10:30 AM today') ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
// This reads: if current time is after end time, option is selected, otherwise it's not
$end   = (strtotime('now') > strtotime(' 2:30 PM today') ? 'selected="selected"' : '');

?>
```

To use this in your select control, you'd echo the variables (shown in shorthand for brevity) in the options. If the date calculations are correct, that option will be selected, otherwise it will remain unchanged. I removed the selection from the placeholder because this setup will ensure Start or End are always selected.

```
<select name="startfinish" id="startend" required>
  <option disabled selection>Please select</option>
  <option <?=$start?> value="Start">Start</option>
  <option <?=$end?> value="End">End</option>
</select>
```

The benefit of using PHP in this case is that it runs server-side instead of client-side, so you don't have to worry about the user disabling Javascript and ruining your form design. Though, if you're already depending on jQuery in your application that's probably a non-issue.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you didn't realise you could insert things into html like this, will keep that in mind next time i get stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date object and a bit of jQuery to get the result you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/8cuL0k3h/

```
$(function() {

    // Grab the date object and get hours/minutes
    var current = new Date();
    var hours = current.getHours();
    var minutes = current.getMinutes();

    // Check if time is before 10:30am
    if( hours <= 10 && minutes < 30 ) {
        $('#startend').val('Start');
    }

    // Check if time is after 2:30pm
    else if( hours >= 14 && minutes > 30 ) {
        $('#startend').val('End');
    }
});
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me with Chrome, But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the site is statically generated, in which case PHP wont get a bite of this particular apple. Here's a JS only approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    initSelectElement();
}

function makeItemSelected(listElem, index)
{
    var i, n = listElem.options.length;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (index == i)
            listElem.options[i].setAttribute('selected','');
        else
            listElem.options[i].removeAttribute('selected');
    }
}

function initSelectElement()
{
    var curTime = new Date();
    var curHour = curTime.getHours();
    var curMin = curTime.getMinutes();

    if ((curMin <= 30) && (curHour <= 10))
    {
        makeItemSelected(byId('startend'), 1);
    }

    else if ((curMin >= 30) && (curHour >= 2))
    {
        makeItemSelected(byId('startend'), 2);
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="startfinish" id="startend" required>
                <option selected disabled>Please select</option>
                <option value="Start">Start</option>
                <option value="End">End</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried this one, didn't seem to work for me using Chrome.
Thanks for your answer though